# Allow std::expected to use a private constructor

Tags: c++, c++23

I try to create a non-copyable and non-movable class, whose object construction should only be done via a create function instead of public constructors. The create function will return a `std::expected` object either holding the created object or an error object. In order to enforce construction via the create function I want to make all available constructors private. Main purpose of this approach is object construction without exceptions.

Here is a simple example:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    int val_{};

public:
    Foo() = delete;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;

    static auto
    create(int val) noexcept -> std::expected<Foo, std::error_code>
    {
        if (val == 42)
            return std::unexpected<std::error_code>(std::in_place, EINVAL, std::generic_category() );

        return std::expected<Foo, std::error_code>{ std::in_place, val };
    }

private:

    friend class std::expected<Foo, std::error_code>;

    explicit Foo(int val) noexcept
    : val_{ val }
    {};

};
```

Please note, that I made `std::expected<Foo, std::error_code>` a `friend` in order to allow it to call the private constructor. But still I get a compiler error. Here is the code in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7P6z9vPx).

Comment: What's wrong with `return Foo{val};`?

Comment: @Barry, `return Foo{val};` doesn't work: https://godbolt.org/z/bdPc6Eh9q

Comment: Yeah because you made this type neither movable nor copyable, which doesn't make it seem super useful...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `expected::transform`:

```
static auto
create(int val) noexcept -> std::expected<Foo, std::error_code>
{
    if (val == 42)
        return std::unexpected<std::error_code>(std::in_place, EINVAL, std::generic_category() );
    
    return std::expected<int, std::error_code>{val}.transform(
      [](int i) { return Foo{i}; }
    );
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ejahrhxob)

Comment: Nice! ...and it doesn't even require `friend`ship!

Comment: The solution is impressive and solves the problem. However, given that this might be a common use case for exception free programming it is a rather cumbersome solution. It is sad, that the language cannot support this in a better way.

Comment: @k.st. Supporting immovable types is not a "common use case for exception free programming."